# Android Call Recording Issue in Marshmallow and Above Version

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, phone-call, recording, call-recording

I'm working auto call recorder app, I'm able to record voice call on below android Marshmallow using **MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL**, From android marshmallow not able to record voice call using VOICE_CALL. I managed to record using **MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC** but here incoming voice not getting recorded and I want to record voice call in normal mode, not in speaker mode.
I tried many examples and search a lot then I write this question.
Please Help Me.
There is an app on Google play that record both side voice in the call, Named "**Call Recorder - Automatic Call Recorder**" How it is working in marshmallow, Is there any other way to record the call?

```
    int Media;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        Media = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION;
    }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT==23){
        Media = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
    }
    else{
        Media = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL;
    }

    CallRecord callRecord = new CallRecord.Builder(this)
            .setRecordFileName("")
            .setRecordDirName("CallRecord")
            .setRecordDirPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()) 
            .setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
            .setAudioSource(Media) 
            .setShowSeed(true)
            .build();
    callRecord.startCallRecordService();
```

Comment: Hi Kishor, I am also working on callRecording but not working in Above Marshmallow.Have you found solution on this.Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Which library have you used Kishor ?

Comment: rooting a phone to make our app behave like system apps will be a solution? So that we can use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL to record